# How to make rubocop output nothing when there are no warnings or offenses?

Tags: ruby, suppress-warnings, suppress, rubocop

I'd like rubocop but have it create no output if there are no offenses.  I've played with the documented command line options, and taken a quick peek a the config option and source code without seeing anything promising.

The closest I've come is `rubocop -f o`, but even that produces a summary line:

```
$ rubocop -f o

--
0  Total
```

Any ideas on how to suppress output on a clean, successful run?

Comment: Why not pipe the output through `sed` and let it strip `"--\n0  Total"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's no predefined option to do what you ask. The best option I think is to implement a custom formatter with the desired behaviour and use that to run RuboCop. As a super simple example consider the following, inspired by RuboCop's [SimpleTextFormatter](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/lib/rubocop/formatter/simple_text_formatter.rb):

```
# my_rubocop_formatter.rb
class MyRuboCopFormatter < RuboCop::Formatter::BaseFormatter
  def started(target_files)
    @total_offenses = 0
  end
  def file_finished(file, offenses)
    unless offenses.empty?
      output.puts(offenses)
      @total_offenses += offenses.count
    end
  end
  def finished(inspected_files)
    puts @total_offenses unless @total_offenses.zero?
  end
end
```

You can run RuboCop using it with the following command:

```
rubocop -r '/path/to/my_rubocop_formatter.rb' \ 
        -f MyRuboCopFormatter file_to_check.rb
```

Comment: I'm doing just that right now.  I'm  a bit hung up on getting the --require and --format options to actually invoke my new formatter...but I'm sure I'll get past that.  Thanks for the advice, @toro2k !